# Fluentd Throwing error and not uploading data to Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, efk, td-agent

```
unexpected error error_class=Elasticsearch::UnsupportedProductError error="The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch."
```

Comment: Please add details (versions, links, etc.) along with the relevant fluentd config.

Comment: It's most probably related to `Elasticsearch` than `fluentd` but more information is needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.